# When do importing user-defined components need curly braces?

Tags: ecmascript-6

In the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html/) , it writes like:

```html
import React from 'react';
import CustomButton from './CustomButton';
```

But I must write like :

```html
    import React from 'react';
    import {CustomButton} from './CustomButton';
```

Otherwise the console gives me some errors like :

```html
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'ruleObj' has already been declared
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: `CustomButton` must have multiple exports.

Comment: This is export/import syntax: without braces you import `default`, with braces you import named variables

Comment: @DanielA.White I've done that like : export {MyComponents};

Comment: That means you have a named export. You need a "named import" to import a named export. If you don't want that then make a default export: `export default MyComponents;`. This has nothing to do with React. The React documentation assumes you have a default export, because that's what people use when their module only exports a single value.

Comment: @FelixKling THS! I've just now learned some export/import syntax .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be happening because the CustomButton is not exported as default in './CustomButton'.

When a module has a default you don't need {}. That is needed when you export multiple things, and you want to require some of them.